# Merging branch to master

Tags: git

I have two branches: `master` and `feature`. I have made several commits in `feature` branch that makes massive directory structure changes. After doing so, I `checkout`'d the `master` branch and added a `README.md` to root directory. This is the only change I've made to `master` after creating the `feature` branch.

I want to now make it such that the `master` branch is "fast-forwarded" to `feature` (i.e. all changes in `feature` are now in `master`), but I also want to include `master`'s added `README.md`. How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Isn't this the meant behavior of `git merge`? Simply `git checkout master && git merge feature` should do what you want. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess I'm just asking if the `git merge` by default will include changes in `master`. So I don't need any `--strategy=ours` ooption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`git merge <branchname>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).  This will merge changes into your current checked out branch.  So:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Since you've made a change on `master` since you started the `feature` branch (adding the README), this will be done as a "merge commit".  Meaning it will automatically merge and then create a commit.  If you hadn't changed `master`, your branch would simply be fast-forwarded to the current commit of `feature`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git merge` command, which according to `git help` does this:

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their
>   histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.

So, commit your change on `master`, and then `git merge feature`.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be a fast forward, as you made changes to the master branch. You could step back the last change (`git reset HEAD^`), store it away for later (`git stash`), merge your feature in (`git merge feature`), apply the change on top (`git stash apply; git commit  ....`). There are simpler/sneakier ways to get this, but this is easy to understand.
If adding the file was really all you did, you could just step back, do the merge, and add he file again.

Take care, this changes history. If you published the master branch with the change, it won't be a fast forward for somebody following the repo. Thanks to @SamSullivan to point this out.

Comment: Note that this probably will confuse others who were able to clone the repository.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is collaboration, but you should really note that this will cause **big problems** if you have pushed to a remote origin (like GitHub) and other people have pulled your changes. *Don't change history if you have already pushed.*